# Create a generating function for a baskets with fruits

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

A basket holds 10 bananas, 8 apples, 6 oranges and 4 pears. Let $a_i$ be the number of different presents composed of $i$ fruits. Each such present contains at least 1 banana, at most 2 apples, the number of oranges in a present is even, and the number of pears in a present is odd. Create a generating function for ${\{{a_i\}}^\infty_{i=1}}$.

I'm not really sure how to approach this problem, I'd appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generating function
\begin{eqnarray*}
(b+b^2+\cdots+b^{10})(1+a+a^2)(1+o^2+o^4+o^6)(p+p^3)
\end{eqnarray*}
will give the number of choices of fruits and keep tabs on which type of each fruit.

We are only intrested in the number of configurations for a given number of fruits, so let $a=b=o=p=x$ and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_i= [x^i]:(x+x^2+\cdots+x^{10})(1+x+x^2)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6)(x+x^3).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Shouldn't the sequance of a's start at 1 + a + ... etc and end at a^2, if there's at most 2 apples?

Comment: @user747644 Yes. I had misread the question. Thank you for bringing this to my  attention.

Comment: So the value of let's say $a_5$ is the coefficient of $x^5$ in the generating function?

Comment: That's right. $[x^i]:f(x)$ is a coefficient extractor ... it means the coefficient of $x^i$ in the function $f(x)$.